# how to prevent a for loop from overwriting a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am creating a dictionary for a JSON file, through the use of a for loop.
However my `for` loop overwrites the entries

```
second_dict={}
third_dict={}

name=['suzen','lilly','sara']
hobbies=['chess','reading','dancing']
age=[13,14,15]

for i in range(len(name)):
    second_dict["hobbies"]=hobbies[i]
    second_dict["age"]=age[i]
    third_dict[name[i]]=second_dict
print(third_dict)
```

I am getting this output

```
{'suzen': {'hobbies': 'chess', 'age': 13},
'lilly': {'hobbies': 'chess', 'age': 13}, 
 'sara': {'hobbies': 'chess', 'age': 13}}
```

Instead of getting this one

```
{'suzen': {'hobbies': 'chess', 'age': 13},
 'lilly': {'hobbies': 'reading', 'age': 14}, 
 'sara': {'hobbies': 'dancing', 'age': 15}}
```

can anyone please point out my mistake?
thank you

Comment: [mcve] please. How are you creating the `third_dict`?

Comment: Where do you create „second_dict“? Are you reusing the same object?

Comment: I created them as empty dictionaries.. I am reusing second_dict to add another key/value to it.

Comment: Don‘t reuse objects unless you want changes to be visible on each reference.

Comment: instead of this `third_dict[name[i]]=second_dict` do `third_dict[name[i]]=dict(second_dict)` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new_dict={}
name=['suzen','lilly','sara']
hobbies=['chess','reading','dancing']
age=[13,14,15]
x = zip(name, hobbies, age)
for n,h,a in x:
    new_dict[n]={'hobbies': h, 'age': a}

print(new_dict)
```

---

```
third_dict={}
name=['suzen','lilly','sara']
hobbies=['chess','reading','dancing']
age=[13,14,15]

for i in range(len(name)):
    second_dict={}
    second_dict["hobbies"]=hobbies[i]
    second_dict["age"]=age[i]

    third_dict[name[i]]=second_dict
print(third_dict)
```

As pointed in comments, you should create a new object for each `second_dict`, there are 3 `second_dict`.